# If, else with multiple constraints and dialog message function

Tags: java, swing, if-statement

I'm working on a code in eclipse with swing and I have a long-ish if, else function that I'm having trouble with. So, I kind of forgot about nested if, else functions and made all the if's separate, which of course only brings back the last if as true. I want the else function to take into consider multiple constraints, but how do I do this when each "if" has its own dialog message that pops up?

I tried to just make it one long if function with &&'s and a single dialog message, which would work fine for what I need, but I don't know how to do the confirm password and make sure that's not null with that still having its own dialog message and still being in the same if, else function.

```
btnSubmit = new JButton("Submit");  
            btnSubmit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    JFrame frmregistration_test = new JFrame("Submit");
                    if (p1.getText().isEmpty())
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Password Field field must be filled in", "Login Warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                    }

                    if (p2.getText().isEmpty())
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Confirm password Field field must be filled in", "Login Warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                    }


                    if (p1 != null && p2 != null) {
                    if (!Arrays.equals(p1.getPassword(), p2.getPassword())) 
                    {   
                           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Passwords do not match.", "Woops", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);


                    }
                    if (txtname.getText().isEmpty())
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Name field must be filled in", "Login Warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                    }
                    if (txtDOB.getText().isEmpty())
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "DOB field must be filled in", "Login Warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                    }
                    if (txtNum.getText().isEmpty())
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Phone Number field must be filled in", "Login Warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                    }
                    if (txtState.getText().isEmpty())
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "State field must be filled in", "Login Warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                    }
                    if (txtid.getText().isEmpty())
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Email Field field must be filled in", "Login Warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);

                    }


                    else 

                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Registered Successfully", "Login Warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                    }



                }});
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) The IDE is not relevant to the question. Don't add IDE tags unless they are directly relevant.

Comment: Nothing wrong with **if, else if, else**. You might however consider using only one call to a Message dialog. Your **if**'s and **else**'s should perhaps place the desired message text into a string variable. If the message variable contains something then display that message in a dialog and exit the method, for example: `String msg = ""; If (blah == blah) { msg = "Message 1"; } else if (blah == blah2) { msg = "Message 2"; } If (!msg.equals("")) { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, msg, "Login Warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE); return; }`.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why simply using `else if` won't work?

```java
btnSubmit = new JButton("Submit");  
btnSubmit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
    {
        JFrame frmregistration_test = new JFrame("Submit");

        if (p1.getText().isEmpty())
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Password Field field must be filled in", "Login Warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }

        else if (p2.getText().isEmpty())
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Confirm password Field field must be filled in", "Login Warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }    

        else if (p1 != null && p2 != null) 
        {
            if (!Arrays.equals(p1.getPassword(), p2.getPassword())) 
            {   
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Passwords do not match.", "Woops", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }

            else if (txtname.getText().isEmpty())
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Name field must be filled in", "Login Warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            }

            else if (txtDOB.getText().isEmpty())
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "DOB field must be filled in", "Login Warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            }

            else if (txtNum.getText().isEmpty())
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Phone Number field must be filled in", "Login Warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            }

            else if (txtState.getText().isEmpty())
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "State field must be filled in", "Login Warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            }

            else if (txtid.getText().isEmpty())
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Email Field field must be filled in", "Login Warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            }

            else 
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Registered Successfully", "Login Warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            }
        }    
    }
});
```